# Monitor on sleep mode if I connect to vga card

Tags: sleep, vga

My monitor going to sleep mode if I connect to my nvidia VGA card card.
LG monitor saying "SLEEP MODE ACTIVATED" Red light is blinking 
BUT 
I connect to my on board VGA it's working properly....
Please Help

Advance thanks .....

Comment: Usual things are check both Graphic card and Monitor drivers and if your OS has any updates. It's basic but often solves a lot of issues. Also try different display adapters, such as DVI and HDMI if possible as I've had issues with this before with display ports.

Comment: But I can't turn on my computer

Comment: What do you mean you can't turn on your PC? If you mean there is no display when you connect to your VGA card, then plug into the MB VGA port. Then look up the model's drivers and install, restart and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have tried booting in safe mode without success try the following.

1. Power down.
2. Remove nVidia card
3. Plug in monitor to onboard VGA
4. Power up
5. Set graphics resolution to 600x800
6. Power down
7. Reinstall the nVidia card
8. Plug in monitor to nVidia card
9. Power-up

Assuming there is now some display showing

- Check drivers, etc in device manager
- change graphics resolution to your normal preference incrementally
  by going up one step at a time and "applying" (as opposed to
  clicking OK).  If one of the selected higher resolutions causes
  the monitor to blank just wait (or press Esc).  The changes will
  revert.